# How to set ng-dirty/ng-pristine on custom element directive with input inside template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angularjs-directive

I have build a form element using a custom directive in AngularJS.

Custom element in form:

```
<form class="login-form" name="loginForm">
    <elm-input-text class="has_bottomSpace" name="email" ng-model="email" required></elm-input-text>
</form>
```

Directive:

```
app.directive("elmInputText", function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                ngModel: '=ngModel',
                name: '@'
            },
            templateUrl: 'src/templates/input-text-template.html'
        };
    });
```

Template:

```
<div class="inputText">
    <input class="inputText-input" ng-model="ngModel" name="{{name}}">
    <label>Label</label>
</div>
```

I want the div to behave like a normal form element in every way, so I'm mostly interested in the class names that are attached to that element and not the class names that are attached to the  inside the template.

I got this already working for the ng-valid/ng-invalid class and also the ng-model reflects the value inside the input. The problem I'm facing now is that ng-pristine/ng-dirty are only applied on the input and not on the div. How can I fix this?

Comment: I'm confused, you said you are `interested in the class names that are attached to that element`, but you have `replace: true` flag set. BTW, could you show how you achieve the same with `ng-valid/ng-invalid/ng-model`?

Comment: I agree, with @runTarm

Comment: Yeah indeed, I actually meant the class names that are attached to the <div class="inputText">, not the <elm-input-text> because that one of course disappears due to replace: true.
 - 
Let's simply the question: The only thing I'm trying to achieve here is that the ng-dirty class will appear on the div, just like it appears already on the input. Now ng-pristine doesn't get replaced on the div.

Comment: The easiest would be putting the `ng-form` on the div. But why exactly do you do something like this, it sound strange for me to have two `ng-model` that binding the same property and have the same name.

Comment: The main reason is that I want this piece of html in a template. If there is some other way to achieve that, I would also like that!